# Import wxPython-Phoenix into Python 3.6 script

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

For Python 3.6, I've installed the package "wxPython-Phoenix" into a Conda environment.  The API indicates that it is imported with "wx".  But that doesn't work:

```
   runfile('/Users/bill/AnacondaProjects/ExcelMigration/DataMigrate.py', wdir='/Users/bill/AnacondaProjects/ExcelMigration')
<class 'ImportError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-aa949bc00bad>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/bill/AnacondaProjects/ExcelMigration/DataMigrate.py', wdir='/Users/bill/AnacondaProjects/ExcelMigration')

  File "/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/bill/AnacondaProjects/ExcelMigration/DataMigrate.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dfgui

  File "/Users/bill/AnacondaProjects/ExcelMigration/dfgui.py", line 15, in <module>
    import wx

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'
```

The actual package name is wxPython-Phoenix but the name space is wx.

I've also tried import with "__" rather than "-"; the "-" throws a syntax error.  The "_" throws "No module named 'wxPython_Phoenix'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered - the path for wx when installed via conda for some reason requires a more specific reference.  I added the direct path to wx.py in the sys.path and the import was able to find the library...